# add clickhandler to widgets in a tree

Tags: gwt, event-handling, handler

i have a problem with a clickhandler which is part of a widget in a treeitem.

If i clicked firstime on this widget, the handler from the treeItem gets fired. If i clicked on this widget a second time both handler are fired.

Is there a way to deactive the treehandler for one TreeItem?
I've the following code:

```java
TreeItem subTree= new TreeItem(type.toString());
        ....
            HorizontalPanel panel= new HorizontalPanel();
            panel.setWidth("200px");
            Label folderLabel= new Label(folder);
            folderLabel.setWidth("200px");
            panel.add(folderLabel);
            Image choosen= new ChooseFolderImage(type, folder);
            choosen.setSize("20px", "20px");
            panel.add(choosen);
            choosen.addHandler(handler, ClickEvent.getType());
            subTree.addItem(panel);
        ....
        rootTree.addItem(subTree);
```

greetings,
destiny

Comment: damn! this codesnippet works very well...the problem was in another part of the code.Sry, need more coffee :>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I did the following:

1. I created a new GWT project
2. I copy pasted your code in my `onModuleLoad()` method in my class
   which extends `EntryPoint`
3. I ran the project

It perfectly works fine, there must be some other erroneous place of your code.

Comment: btw, in my treeHandler i checked everytime if the new treeitem is equivalent to the old. So i save a lot overhead because the treeHandler is activated,too if i clicked on the image

Comment: yeah, that will be a very nice approach indeed!